# Adding control symbols to a byte stream

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Problem: sometimes we have to interleave multiple streams into one,
in which case its necessary to provide a way to identify block
boundaries within a stream. What kind of format would be good
for such a task? 
(All processing has to be purely sequential and i/o operations are
blockwise and aligned.)

1. From decoding side, the best way is to have length prefixes
   for blocks. But at encoding side, it requires either random access
   to output file (seek to stream start and write the header), or
   being able to cache the whole streams, which is, in general, impossible.
2. Alternatively, we can add length headers (+ some flags) to
   blocks of cacheable size. Its surely a solution, but handling is much more
   complex than [1], especially at encoding (presuming that i/o operations
   are done with aligned fixed-size blocks).
   Well, one possible implementation is to write a 0 byte into the buffer,
   then stream data until its filled. So prefix byte = 0 would mean that
   there're bufsize-1 bytes of stream data next, and !=0 would mean that
   there's less... in which case we would be able to insert another prefix
   byte if end-of-stream is reached. This would only work with bufsize=32k
   or so, because otherwise the block length would require 3+ bytes to store,
   and there would be a problem with handling of the case with end-of-stream
   when there's only one byte of free space in the buffer.
   (One solution to that would be storing 2-byte prefixes to each buffer
   and adding 3rd byte when necessary; another is to provide a 2-byte encoding
   for some special block lengths like bufsize-2).
   Either way its no so good, because even 1 extra byte per 64k would accumulate
   to a noticeable number with large files (1526 bytes per 100M). Also hardcoding
   of the block size into format is bad too.
3. Escape prefix. Eg. EC 4B A7 00 = EC 4B A7,  EC 4B A7 01 = end-of-stream.
   Now this is really easy to encode, but decoding is pretty painful - requires
   a messy state machine even to extract single bytes.
   But overall it adds least overhead, so it seem that we still need to find
   a good implementation for buffered decoding.
4. Escape prefix with all same bytes (Eg. FF FF FF). Much easier to check,
   but runs of the same byte in the stream would produce a huge overhead (like 25%),
   and its not unlikely with any byte value chosen for escape code.
5. Escape postfix. Store the payload byte before the marker - then decoder
   just has to skip 1 byte before masked marker, and 4 bytes for control code.
   So this basically introduces a fixed 4-byte delay for decoder, while [3]
   has a complex path where marker bytes have to be returned one by one.
   Still, with [3] encoder is much simpler (it just has to write an extra 0
   when marker matches), and this doesn't really simplify the buffer processing.

Update: Actually I'm pretty sure that [3] or [5] would be the option I'd use,
I only listed other options in hope to get more alternatives (for example, it
would be ok if redundancy is 1 *bit* per block on average). So the main question
atm is how to parse the stream for [3]... current state machine looks like this:

```
int saved_c;
int o_last, c_last;
int GetByte( FILE* f ) {
  int c;

  Start:
  if( o_last>=10 ) {
    if( c_last>=(o_last-10) ) { c=saved_c; o_last=0; }
    else c=byte("\xEC\x4B\xA7"[c_last++]);
  } else {
    c = getc(f); 
    if( o_last<3 ) {
      if( char(c)==("\xEC\x4B\xA7"[o_last]) ) { o_last++; goto Start; } 
      else if( o_last>0 ) { saved_c=c; c_last=0; o_last+=10; goto Start; } // 11,12
      // else just return c
    } else {
      if( c>0 ) { c=-1-c, o_last=0; printf( "c=%i\n", c ); }
      else { saved_c=0xA7; c_last=0; o_last+=10-1; goto Start; } // 12
    }
  }

  return c;
}
```

and its certainly ugly (and slow)

Comment: Regarding solution #2: You think that an overhead of 1 byte over 64k is unacceptable??? It's less than 1% of 1%. There is probably far more overhead on whatever medium (disk or network) you'll be streaming to.

Comment: I don't think that its unacceptable, but its pretty annoying to gain 10k due to complex optimization of compression algorithm, while knowing that 100k is lost at these headers. Anyway, [3] introduces much less redundancy, and much simpler to encode, but decoding is a bit of a mess...

Comment: Perhaps you should go with what's easiest to implement, and only worry about overhead once you start exceeding a few %. The same reasoning goes for execution speed.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not writing the first archiver in the world, so having more redundancy than existing compressors _is_ unacceptable.

Comment: So your compression algorithm gives you less than one byte savings  over 64k? Why bother compressing at all?

Comment: There're always data that cannot be compressed (archives, for example) - and its not so good to introduce even a single byte of redundancy when i can't compress the data.

Comment: Oh, ok. I now see why you're trying to squeeze every byte. Perhaps you should explain the background behind your question a little more in your question.

Comment: Anyway, there're both speed and redundancy issues, and I don't want to use the first thing that works, because maintaining it would be a pain later (while being unable to change the format, because some files are already stored using it).

Comment: Its actually a pretty common problem (escape-coding for alphabet extension), so I don't think that background really matters. Just that I ended up with a mess like this - http://pastebin.com/vcxaDB5u

Comment: You've listed all the tricks I've seen for packetizing data in communication protocols. I don't know if there's a silver bullet that's easy to encode/decode, fast, and has minimal overhead, easy to program, etc. all at the same time. I'm hoping an expert in this matter will step in and provide this magic solution. :-)

Comment: Well, I specially added 4-5 to show that even simple changes can significantly affect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the ugly parser from OP in my actual project
( http://encode.ru/threads/1231-lzma-recompressor )

But now it seems that the actual answer is to let data type handlers
to terminate their streams however they want, which means that escape coding
in case of uncompressed data, but when some kind of entropy coding is
used in the stream, its usually possible to incorporate a more efficient EOF code.

Answer (score 1):

How about using blocks of fixed size, e.g. 1KB?
Each block would contain a byte (or 4 bytes) indicating which stream it is, and then it follows with just data.

Benefits:

- You don't have to pay attention regarding the data itself. Data cannot accidently trigger any behaviour from your system (e.g. accidently terminate the stream)
- I does not require random file access when encoding. In particular, you don't store the length of the block as it is fixed.
- If data goes corrupt, the system can recover in the next block.

Drawbacks:

- If you have to switch from stream to stream a lot, with each having only few bytes of data, the block may be underutilised. Lots of bytes will be empty.
- If the block size is too small (e.g. if you want to solve the above problem), you can get huge overhead from the header.

Comment: Its basically for a data compression format, so no sense to add so much - as it is (and common formats have larger blocks, like 32k) it seems pretty wrong when 100M of zeroes is compressed to 100k of "random" data, although 4 bytes could be enough

Comment: So you want to compress some input multi-stream data, but keep the streams intact, right? So that, for example, one could decompress only one stream without touching the rest?

Comment: Atm I just want to compress parts of the input stream, while passing other parts uncompressed; so i have to switch them somehow.

Comment: @Shelwien It really sounds like you need to provide more details of what you're trying to do and what your constraints are. Nobody's going to be able to give a useful answer with hidden requirements constantly showing up.

Comment: I just need to interleave/deinterleave the byte streams, and hoped to get some new ideas for that. For example, one option which I didn't list is arithmetic coding - it allows to add control symbols with any specified redundancy.

Comment: Let me ask this: How many streams you have, what is their typical length and how often do you need to switch from one stream to another? Depending on these statistics, the best solution may vary. The best option - in terms of memory usage - would be to not interleave at all; just put one stream after another.

Answer (score 0):

From a standpoint of simplicity for sequential read and write, I would take solution 1, and just use a short buffer, limited to 256 bytes. Then you have a one-byte length followed by data. If a single stream has more than 256 consecutive bytes, you simply write out another length header and the data.

If you have any further requirements though you might have to do something more elaborate. For instance random-access reads probably require a magic number that can't be duplicated in the real data (or that's always escaped when it appears in the real data).

Comment: Further requirements are minimum redundancy and minimum complexity. Its intended for processing of GBs of data.